# Выборка последних значений по уникальным значениям одного столбца

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица вида:

```
id  name    state   date
1   Alice   1   23-03-2018 12:41:31
2   Alice   1   23-03-2018 12:41:42
3   Bob     1   23-03-2018 12:42:18
4   John    1   23-03-2018 12:42:19
5   Alice   2   23-03-2018 12:42:19
6   Alice   1   23-03-2018 12:43:35
7   John    2   23-03-2018 12:43:36
```

Каким образом можно выбрать из неё данные за последние 5 минут и из этих данных получить самые свежие записи по каждому из имен в столбце name?
Результатом должно быть:

```
3   Bob     1   23-03-2018 12:42:18
6   Alice   1   23-03-2018 12:43:35
7   John    2   23-03-2018 12:43:36
```

Я пробовал:

```
SET @@sql_mode = "";
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `date`  > (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY `name`
```

Оно показывает уникальные имена за указанное время, но записи там не самые свежие из имеющихся.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `date`=(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM `users`) AND `name`=(SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `users`)
Такой вариант не работает
Хочу выбрать сперва все уникальные значения из столбца name и потом найти строки с результатами name с максимальным date

Comment: select distinct `name`, `state`, max(`date`) as `date` from `users` group by `name`;
Как мне великодушно подсказали, вот такой вариант выбирает по каждому уникальному имени запись из таблицы. Как ограничить время выборки 5ю минутами?